# Trouble deserialize JSON with RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, json, restsharp

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON response from WooCommerce with RestSharp.
I've been crawling this site for similar posts, but haven't found any solution.

My JSON (simplified)

```
[
    {
        "id":1,
        "name":"product 1",
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "name":"product 2",
    }
]
```

Which translates into C# like this:

```
public class ProductResponse
{
    public List<Product> products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

And is called like this

```
var response = client.Execute<ProductResponse>(request);
```

But it doesn't work, as the array of products doesn't have a name.
If the JSON is changed to

```
{
    "products":
    [
        {
            "id":1,
            "name":"product 1",
        },
        {
            "id":2,
            "name":"product 2",
        }
    ]
}
```

It works like a charm. Unfortunately I'm not able to change the JSON-format.
So how do I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tested here. The problem is that the JSON that you are receiving is malformed.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to remove the comma after the last property in each of the objects - with those removed it's valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate your product class to tell RestSharp which property is which:

```
public class Product
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var response = client.Execute<List<Product>>(request);
```

You should now have a `List<Product>` with two correctly populated entries.

---

**Original answer for posterity:**

I don't have an answer for RestSharp (yet) but you could achieve this easily with [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) if you can use that.

You can use the [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) annotation like so:

```
public class Product
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    int id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(json);
```

Comment: Of course - that makes sense. I've changed to var response = client.Execute<List<Product>>(request); and can remove the ProductResponse class. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think your deserialization actually should be `List<Product>` rather than `ProductResponse`.

E.g.

```
var response = client.Execute<List<Product>>(request);

Console.WriteLine("id = " + response[0].id)      //  id = 1  
Console.WriteLine("name = " + response[0].name)  //  name = product 1
Console.WriteLine("id = " + response[1].id)    //  id = 2
Console.WriteLine("name = " + response[1].name)  //  name = product 2
```

So there is nothing wrong with the JSON string, I think the problem is you are expecting an object of type `ProductResponse`, where as your JSON string is an array/List of type `Product`.